# Dependent methods in the same class run out of order only when included in a “testng suite”; running class independently respects the dependency

Tags: webdriver, selenium2, java, testng

I have a class with dependent methods using the TestNG annotation

```
dependsOnMethods
```

The test runs fine 100% of the time if I simply run it as a TestNG Test from the package.

When I include the test in a TestNG Suite, the methods run out of order. Yes, I am using:

```
<test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
```

in my .xml file.

Every other test in the suite respects the method ordering and run without issue. Is there any known information on why this might be occurring?

Test code:

```
@Test(groups={ "Administration"})
public class RoleCrudTest extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{
protected static SeleniumActionHelper action;

    @Test
    public void inactiveRole() throws Exception
    {
        SeleniumHelper helper = new SeleniumHelper();
        action = new SeleniumActionHelper(driver);

        helper.login();

        String roleUrl = navigateToUrl("role/roles.xhtml");
        driver.get(roleUrl);

        assertEquals("Role:", findElementBySelector("span.portletButtonHeader").getText());

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        assertFalse(roleName.isEnabled());

        WebElement deptId = findElementById("deptid");
        assertFalse(deptId.isEnabled());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "inactiveRole")
    public void createRole() throws Exception
    {
        WebElement addButton = findElementById("add");
        addButton.click();

        waitUntilAjaxRequestCompletes();

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.sendKeys("AAAAAAAA");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[2]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement save = findElementById("save");
        save.click();

        assertEquals("Role saved successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "createRole")
    public void editUndo() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement tableSort = findElementByXpath("//th[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped:j_idt85']/div/span[2]");
        tableSort.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement createdRole = findElementByXpath("//tbody[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped_data']/tr[1]/td/div");
        createdRole.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.clear();
        roleName.sendKeys("edited");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[3]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div/span");
        checkbox.click();

        WebElement checkbox2 = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:0']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox2.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement undo = findElementById("cancel");
        undo.click();

        String text = findElementById("roleName").getAttribute("value");
        String oldtext = "AAAAAAAA";

        assertTrue(text.equals(oldtext));
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "editUndo")
    public void editRole() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement createdRole = findElementByXpath("//tbody[@id='tableSection:rolesListWrapped_data']/tr[1]/td/div");
        createdRole.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement roleName = findElementById("roleName");
        roleName.click();
        roleName.clear();
        roleName.sendKeys("AAAAAAAAedited");

        WebElement deptId = findElementByXpath("(//button[@type='button'])[3]");
        deptId.click();

        WebElement dept = findElementByXpath("//div[@id='department_panel']/ul/li[3]");
        dept.click();

        WebElement checkbox = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:1']/div/span/div/div/span");
        checkbox.click();

        WebElement checkbox2 = findElementByXpath("//li[@id='privileges:0']/div/span/div/div");
        checkbox2.click();

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement save = findElementById("save");
        save.click();

        assertEquals("Role saved successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());
    }

    @Test(dependsOnMethods = "editRole")
    public void deleteRole() throws Exception
    {
        Thread.sleep(1000);

        WebElement deleteButton = findElementById("tableSection:delete");
        deleteButton.click();

        WebElement deleteConfirm = findElementById("confirmDelete:yes");
        deleteConfirm.click();

        Thread.sleep(500);

        assertEquals("Role deleted successfully", findElementBySelector("div.ui-growl-message > p").getText());

        waitUntilAjaxRequestCompletes();
    }
}
```

And here is the entire TestNG XML file (please note that this is a simple one with only 3 classes, the behavior is the same if I run an XML with 20 classes).  No matter the amount of classes or ordering, the roleCrud test always runs the methods out of order, every other class runs fine:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" parallel="none">
  <test name="Test" preserve-order="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.x.c4i.view.security.RoleCreateErrorCheckTest"/>
      <class name="com.x.c4i.view.security.GroupCrudTest"/>
      <class name="com.x.c4i.view.security.RoleCrudTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

Comment: test code snippet, more of your testng.xml may help others in helping you

Comment: test code attached

Comment: Don't see any thing obviously wrong, can you post testng.xml file and order in which you see method execution in this class. Is the order always random for this class?

Comment: Updated with the entire TestNG.xml file.  The method execution I see is inactiveRole->editUndo->editRole->createRole.  However, sometimes editUndo and editRole get switched in position

Comment: Yet I don't see any thing wrong. I suggest you to post it here - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/testng-users with a reproducible test case which demonstrate this issues.

Comment: @squeemish Did you ever get a response?

Comment: nope, no response :(

Comment: I have reported this on GitHub https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/261. This issue https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/97 might be related too, if not duplicate. In my opinion it is a bug waiting to be fixed.

Comment: Did the resolution of yurloc's issue help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Per the resolution of the [GitHub issue yurloc filed](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/261), it appears that using `group-by-instances` will prevent tests from being interleaved when using `dependsOnMethods`.

Comment: Sigh. Try to button up an unanswered question and get a downvote with no explanation. I would hope the downvoter knows more about TestNG than I do, in which case they might have also known enough to provide a better answer.

Comment: 4 years later.. Thanks a lot for your answer! I already had a headache from this one... puh